# How to add operator for rapidminer

Tags: plugins, jar, operators, data-mining, rapidminer

everyone

Thanks for reading my question. I am doing a project with Rapidminer, I have to add a new algorithm as a operator in Rapidminer, I'm just a beginner, I have been read some docs about this, but I still don't know how to do it, so I need your help to give some solutions.

What I know now, we have two solutions to add or change a operator

1. click right button on a operator which exist already in Rapidminer's operators.
2. import Rapidminer project in Eclipse

But, I just download Rapidminer, I didn't found the operation 'edit source code' when I clicked right button on a operator.

And if I import the project, whether I have to import the whole project on github? Or I just need import some jars.

Once I finish my 'operator', I just need to export the jar of my 'operator' and put it in the folder of 'plugin' in the location of installation Rapidminer? If just like what I say, It will be not easy for debug...?

Please give me some suggestions about my project as you can.
Thank you very much.

Jiang

Comment: Could you tell which documents have your read? Was How to extend RapidMiner 5 (http://1xltkxylmzx3z8gd647akcdvov.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/How-to-Extend-RapidMiner-5.pdf) among those? I have to admit I have never heard of your first option. I would recommend following the guide I linked. Checking out the whole source of RapidMiner can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm reading this document now, is very helpful now.

Comment: I am sorry to distrub you again, in this document, it mentioned I can import two "zips" "RapideMiner_Extension_Template" and RapideMiner_Extension_Tutoria". but I can't find these two, it is not available now?

Comment: I am afraid those are no longer available: https://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?topic=5802.0

Comment: Oh... I see. Thanks, By the way, Do you have same exmples about it? could you just send me a exemple to my email if you could?

Comment: I am afraid I do not have them. Probably you can use the sources of existing extensions. (I guess the http://sourceforge.net/p/rapidminer/code/HEAD/tree/Plugins/Reporting/ might be a good start, it seems to be a simple one.) Also the http://www-ai.cs.uni-dortmund.de/SOFTWARE/RMD/index.html extension might help in development.

Comment: Thanks Gabor Bakos, I am flowing the link that you proposed to me. but   you know I am new in this field, it's a little diffcult to do without document, the "how to extend rapidminer 5" is little bit difficult if I don't have files which it mentioned, I encounter lots of problem here... but , I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this template? http://activeintelligence.org/var/RapidMiner_Extension_Template.zip Maybe this would work for you. It is from this page: http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/extending-rapidminer/

Comment: I got your zip, it works!  thank you so so much!!! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize the suggested solution: the [RapidMiner documentation page](http://rapidminer.com/documentation/) suggest [How to extend RapidMiner](http://1xltkxylmzx3z8gd647akcdvov.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/How-to-Extend-RapidMiner-5.pdf)<strike>, although the sources are no longer available (probably to be updated to RapidMiner 6). An alternative location for the sources is http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/extending-rapidminer/ with the http://activeintelligence.org/var/RapidMiner_Extension_Template.zip template project</strike>.
Here is the template: https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-template (according to [this](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,7711.msg26484.html) post.)